# How to get percentages using rpart

Tags: r, rpart

So I'm working on a project with decision trees, and I need to know how to get the percentages for each of the nodes.

Here is my approximate code:

```
fit <- rpart(Y ~ a + b + c, method = "class", data = example, control = rpart.control(minsplit=5))
```

My main question is how do I get the percentage estimation for each of the rows in example from the rpart output.

I have looked at the answer given in the following post [How to get percentages from decision tree for each node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727149/how-to-get-percentages-from-decision-tree-for-each-node), and from my understanding (please correct me if I'm wrong), 33.3% of the data belong in class 2, 36% in class 4, and 30.67% in class 5. But what my question differs is that I need to know is what is the percent chance of an entry being in class 2, what percent chance in class 4, etc.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: how is your question different? please add a reproducible example

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would just want the predicted/fitted values from the tree. `predict(fit, example)` should give you this. For example, if I do `mod = rpart(Species ~ ., data = iris)`, and then `predict(mod)`, it will give the class probabilities for each row in the `iris` dataset.

Answer (score 0):

We have an environment where we cannot use the R [rattle library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rattle/index.html) which includes fancyRpartPlot - a wrapper for plotting rpart trees using prp, so I found the way to do this was to use a [function to access the rpart object frame](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/rpart-plot-without-scientific-notation-td3767975.html) as follows:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(rpart)
node.fun <- function(x, labs, digits, varlen) {    
    avg  <- sprintf("%0.1f", x$frame$yval)
    pct   <- sprintf("%1.1f%%",100*x$frame$wt/x$frame$wt[1]) 
    rows <- format(x$frame$n, big.mark=",")
    paste0(avg, "\n", " n=", rows,"   ", pct)
}
fit <- rpart(skips ~ Opening + Solder + Mask + PadType + Panel, data = solder, method = "anova")
rpart.plot::prp( fit, main="Formatted averages (no scientific notation) and percentages calculated", varlen=0, faclen=0,fallen.leaves=TRUE, shadow.col="gray", nn=TRUE, type = 4, extra = 101, box.palette="Greens", compress=TRUE, tweak=1,node.fun = node.fun)
```

Which gives a rpart plot / tree image that is similar to:

```
library(rattle)
fancyRpartPlot(fit)
```